# Unable to install npm on mac

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

When I try to run this command -- `npm -v` , I get the following crap on the mac command line

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:63:25)
    at EventEmitter.log (native)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:137:21)
    at EventEmitter.info (native)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:20:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:86:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:404:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
```

Comment: This error pops up when another node server is running and you are trying to invoke a new instance of node and there cannot be more than one running node instance at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I've avoided installing node on a Mac using the normal methods (mostly because of the permission issues with /usr/local), and instead switched to using NVM:
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

It'll install node and npm into your home directory, and allow you to switch versions of node on the fly (similar to RVM for Ruby).

And I'd suggest uninstalling node/npm: [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)